# error creating lambda function with terrafrom getting validation error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam

I am using teraform-aws-lambda module and terraform-aws-iam module, follwing these examples, however i have getting validation exception error (output below)

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/tree/master/examples/simple
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-iam/tree/master/examples/iam-assumable-role

```
resource "random_pet" "this" {
    length = 2
}

module "lambda_function" {
    source = "../../modules/terraform-aws-lambda"

    publish = true

    # function_name = "${random_pet.this.id}-copyAMI"
    function_name = "Test-copyAMI"
    handler       = "index.lambda_handler"
    runtime       = "python3.8"

    create_role = false
    lambda_role = module.iam_assumable_role_custom.iam_role_name

    attach_policy = true
    policy = module.iam_policy.arn

    timeout = 600
    

    source_path = [
        "${path.module}/../../src/copy_ami.py",
    ]
}
```

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}


module "iam_assumable_role_custom" {
  source = "../../modules/iam-assumable-role"


  trusted_role_services = [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]

  create_role = true

  role_name         = "LambdaFunction-1"
  role_requires_mfa = false

  custom_role_policy_arns = [
    module.iam_policy.arn
  ]

  role_permissions_boundary_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:policy/BasePolicy"
}


module "iam_policy" {
  source = "../../modules/iam-policy"

  name        = "LambdaFunction-1"
  path        = "/"
  description = "AMI Copy IAM Policy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
                "sts:*",
                "ec2:CopyImage",
                "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

```
module.lambda_function.aws_lambda_function.this[0]: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): ValidationException: 
│   status code: 400, request id: ecf44929-bfa5-4058-89aa-f6ecdacf359e
│ 
│   with module.lambda_function.aws_lambda_function.this[0],
│   on ../../modules/terraform-aws-lambda/main.tf line 19, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "this":
│   19: resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
│
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lambda_role](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda#input_lambda_role) is **IAM role ARN**, not name. So it should be:

```
lambda_role = module.iam_assumable_role_custom.iam_role_arn
```